# MOSFET dimmer IR controlled

Tags: led, hardware, ir, remote-control, mosfet

I am trying to make a group of LED dim with PWM to a MOSFET. The code seems to work for this, but the trouble is that the IR receiver will only receive the signal to turn on the lights and then IR receivers onboard LED goes to a permanent dim state (which is suppose to be off completely).  It then refuses to take input until a Arduino reset is preformed.  I purchased another IR receiver and placed it in the same configuration and it work exactly as intended I could brighten the LEDS and I saw the PWM stretch on my oscilloscope with every click of my remote.  The trouble is that the receiver quickly quit working at this point I think there is a problem with my circuit.  I am attaching the circuit diagram in hopes that someone can help.

Thanks,
Billa

```
#include <IRremote.h>

int led = 9;           
int led2 = 10;
int brightness = 0;    // how bright the LED is
const int RECV_PIN = 7; //IR Receiver Pin
IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;

void setup() {
  // declare pin 9 to be an output:
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led2, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  irrecv.enableIRIn();

}

void loop() {

  analogWrite(led, brightness);
  analogWrite(led2, brightness);


  if(irrecv.decode(&results)) //this checks to see if a code has been received
{
    if(results.value == 0xFF906F) //if the button press equals the hex value 0xC284
    {
        Serial.println("Triggered U");
        brightness = brightness + 5;
    }

    if(results.value == 0xFFE01F) //if the button press equals the hex value 0xC284
    {
        Serial.println("Triggered D");
        brightness = brightness + 5;
    }

    irrecv.resume(); //receive the next value
}



  delay(100);
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the receiver?

Comment: that sure is an ugly schematic

Comment: what's mosfet part number? why there isn't a resistor between arduino and mosfet?

Comment: I don't think, that a resistor between Arduino and MOSFET is really necessary, since a MOSFET normally has only a very small capacitance. But a current limiting resistor for the LEDs would be good

Comment: @jsotola That's what you get for using Fritzing...

Comment: @chrisl It is probably LED strips with built in resistors (since it's powered from 12V). Also the LEDs are backwards, but we'll overlook that ;)

Comment: @newbie A resistor is not strictly needed. I add a 100Ω resistor normally just to limit inrush current to the gate when switching, but then I usually use more powerful MCUs with a lower current rating on each pin than an 8-bit AVR.

Comment: The receiver is a MagicW Digital 38khz Ir Receiver. The MOSFET part number is P30NO6LE. I have also appended the code to the bottom. Sorry for the ugly schematic. If there is a recommend format for Stack Exchange schematics I'd be happy to remake it in that more readable format.

Comment: @ZackGarris - There is a recommended format for drawing schematics: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28251/rules-and-guidelines-for-drawing-good-schematics

Comment: Question about MOSFET gate resistor: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/68748/question-about-mosfet-gate-resistor

Comment: @VE7JRO So you think this could be caused by Ringing (parasitic oscillation)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error I see with the sketch is right under this line of code `Serial.println("Triggered D");`. You are incrementing the variable `brightness` when you probably meant to decrement it.

The second error is with your call to `analogWrite()`. This function accepts an `integer` between 0 and 255. You do not [constrain](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/math/constrain/) the value to that range, and can see what I mean by adding this line of code `Serial.println(brightness);` right above this one `irrecv.resume();` in your sketch. Going from 0 to -5 turns the LED from off to maximum brightness. Is this what you want it to do?

The errors with your MOSFET circuit is a "General Electronics" question, and should be asked on electronics.stackexchange.com. As I mentioned in one of my comments to your question, there is a [recommended format for drawing schematics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28251/rules-and-guidelines-for-drawing-good-schematics).

My other comment was regarding [this Q+A at EE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/68748/question-about-mosfet-gate-resistor). You won't find a consensus on exactly how to use a MOSFET there either, but the [image in this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/68754/165322) may be helpful to you.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I tried the ringing solution with no luck. I'll move my question to over the General Electronics and see.